# Magento2 prouduct edit error

Tags: magento2, product

When i edit product in magento2 i am getting below error guide me what should i do?

> Undefined offset: 90 in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php
>   on line 168

Answer (score 0):

Is your database migrated by any chance? In your case 90 is attribute id, check your database table eav_attribute, I believe that the attribute with this id doesn't exist but it is still part of your product. If the attribute doesn't exist find all references to it in other tables and delete records where column attribute_id = 90. Repeat for other ids if necessary.

Content with reference from :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5236

Comment: The id is exist and without delete i want to solve this problem

Comment: @Arjun..I found this attribute in eav_attribute table. also i delete this entry and tried to import duplicate entry for same id. But nothing happens. I am getting *Undefined offset: 90 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php on line 168* again and again. what to do?